# Can a hadoop client leverage the benefit of rack awareness?

Tags: hadoop, akka-stream

I have 10 ingestion machines which use akka stream for data ingestion.
I have a Hadoop cluster of 50 nodes, and run pipelines using Spark Streaming. Hadoop cluster uses the data generated by 10 machines for producing reports.
Can I leverage rack awareness from those 10 machines without adding them as part of a Hadoop cluster?

When I say rack awareness, I mean if those machines are in the same rack as Hadoop data nodes, so using rack awareness, I would want each ingestion machine to upload data to it's nearest datanode instead of random manner, so that I would have less network traffic.

Please let me know if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your setup correctly, this should happen automagically. According to [HDFS Architecture](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html#Replica_Placement:_The_First_Baby_Steps):

> For the common case, when the replication factor is three, **HDFS’s
> placement policy is to put one replica** on the local machine if the
> writer is on a datanode, otherwise **on a random datanode in the same
> rack as that of the writer**, another replica on a node in a different
> (remote) rack, and the last on a different node in the same remote
> rack.

(highlighted is whats relevant to your case if your ingest nodes are not cluster datanodes.)

Comment: appreciate your quick reply@mazaneicha , do you know if client machine needs to be part of topology_mappings.data file on namenode and snamenode . The file which is used by namenode and snamenode for building topology hiearchy.  In my use case hdfs client machine can successfully create directories and upload files, however during the file upload it's not uploading the file in rack aware manner. on hdfs client machine I have updated rack and host information including client machine inside topology_mapping.data file, as well as on namenode and sname node as well. nn and sn can't reach client.

Comment: Depends on your Hadoop configuration, but if it uses external topology script + conf file then it needs to be on NN. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/RackAwareness.html

Comment: Thank you @mazaneicha. I have a follow up question.I have noticed this behaviour that even though my block replicator setting is set to 3, during the upload from client, sometimes 2 blocks are allocated by nn and sometime 3 blocks. when 3 blocks are allocated one of them is from the same rack data node , but when 2 blocks are allocated, none of them are from same rack datanode. is this expected ?

Comment: that deserves a separate question. please include your hadoop version/distro, how its configured (core-site, hdfs-site), and how you check block allocation.